# Are the UTF8 \x11 and \x1D characters valid in Xml?

Tags: c#, xml, utf-8, teamcity

I have a problem with TeamCity attempting to read the trx file emitted by MSTest. The problem is that I'm running a test on an obfuscated application, and a test failure message, including the stacktrace, includes the following (obfuscated) stack trace snippet as text inside a `<Message>` element. (I inserted spaces between & and # to stop stackoverflow hiding the control characters)

> Call stack    at MyClass& #x11;& #x1D;()

TeamCity's parser chokes on this.

Is the trx file valid Xml? Either way, is there an easy way to sanitize my assertion messages (we're using c#) to avoid this issue?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML

Comment: Ok - looks like Microsoft's trx files (which claim to be Xml v1.0) are invalid.